# Multiple Selection tableView

Tags: indexing, swift3, tableview, ios10, multipleselection

A certain part of my app I want the user to be able to select locations in a table, multiple if they want, and have those locations be printed into a label so they can see what they have selected neatly and in front of them. What do I need to put into `didSelectRowAt` indexPath in order to do this? It's all on the same ViewController.

I don't want to go to another view controller when I select a table cell.

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeLocationsPreview: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableLocations: UITableView!
let itemsLocations: [String] = ["Pacific Northwest", "West Coast", "The West", "Midwest", "Great Lakes", "The South", "New England"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsLocations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellLocations: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    cellLocations.textLabel?.text = itemsLocations[indexPath.row]
    return cellLocations
}
```

EDIT

Now whenever I select an item that is farther down from the table, it brings the index out of range error. I don't know why it only happens when I select an item farther down from the table. Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableLocations: UITableView!
let itemsLocations: [String] = ["Pacific Northwest", "West Coast", "The West", "Midwest", "Great Lakes", "The South", "New England"]
@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeLocationsPreview: UILabel!
var locationsPreviewtext = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    locationsPreviewtext.append(itemsLocations[indexPath.row])
    labelGifteeLocationsPreview.text = "\(locationsPreviewtext)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if locationsPreviewtext.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    else {
        let ind = index(ofAccessibilityElement: locationsPreviewtext[indexPath.row])   //this is where I get the index out of range error
        if ind == NSNotFound {
            locationsPreviewtext.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
    labelGifteeLocationsPreview.text = "\(locationsPreviewtext)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath){

        let cell = tableLocations.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

        }else{

            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using this outline.

Comment: The answer should more describe solution. Add some comment.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark){

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

    }else{

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

    }
}
```

Another way and i recommend it

```
var tags = [["id":1,"name":"html"],["id":2,"name":"php"],["id":3,"name":"javascript"],["id":4,"name":"python"]]
var selectedTags = [Int]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tags.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TagsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TagsTableViewCell

    if(selectedTags.contains(tags[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue)){
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if(selectedTags.contains(tags[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue)){
        selectedTags = selectedTags.filter { $0 != tags[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue }
    }
    else{
        selectedTags.append(tags[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue)
    }

    tagsTableView.reloadData()

}
```